# Returning in DOM values of an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

I have an array of objects - each object containing several values.

Since I have got new objects, these are saved in an array. However, I would like to publish this array and the new objects in my DOM. The idea is that my DOM is listing all the objects of my array and every time a new object is created, it's added to my array and updated in my DOM.

I am having a hard time understanding how to publish this in my DOM.

Should I have 2 loops?
- 1 to save the data as an object and add it to my array whenever a new object is triggered
- 1 to publish my array of objects in my DOM (but wouldn't it regenerate the whole table each time, instead of "updating" with the new object only?)

I'm hitting a wall on this thinking process, so if you have advice, they're more than welcome!

So far I have:

1 - declaration of an array of object

2 - function to retrieve input data and assign it to a new object

3 - function to push the object to array

4 - on click, function:
calls function to create an object
calls function to add the object to the table
converts object table to string to publish in DOM

I'm a bit stuck on where to create my loop exactly.

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: You should add the code you're working with as a [mcve]. It will make understanding your question easier.

Comment: Please add your code sample for more detail instead of these long explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description you're trying to do something like this.

```js
// Declare array
const arr = [];

// Cache elements
const input = document.querySelector('input');
const button = document.querySelector('button');
const result = document.querySelector('#result');

// Assign event listener to the button
button.addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);

// When the button is clicked..
function handleClick() {

  // Push the new value/object to the array
  arr.push(input.value);

  // Call the function to update the page
  updatePage();
}

function updatePage() {

  // `map` over the data in the array to return an
  // array of HTML strings, and join them up
  const html = arr.map(el => `<p>${el}</p>`).join('');

  // Set the innerHTML of the result element as the
  // string `html`
  result.innerHTML = html;
}
```

```css
p { color: blue; border: 1px solid red;}
```

```html
<input />
<button>Add</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

So really you only need one loop which creates the HTML you're adding to the page.

Comment: _"but wouldn't it regenerate the whole table each time, instead of "updating" with the new object only"_ - Like in your answer.

Comment: Yes it draws the table each time. So what? There's no way of feeding back on code the OP may or may not have written because none was included in the question, but given the presumably small dataset involved this is a great way to solve the problem.

Comment: @Andreas and Andy, thanks for your replies! I think I'm really confused at this point because Ive been going on circle on this for days. But, I was wondering how to display the existing comments of array on page load, before someone adds a comment causing the update of the array but I guess it can be a separate event which is not triggered by the comment button but on page load, correct?

Comment: _"on code the OP may or may not have written because none was included in the question"_ - that should trigger a "close"-vote from you and not a raw guess as answer.

Comment: Yeah, well it triggered a helpful comment from me asking the OP to add code instead.